# 複数のテーブルの参照を、一つのカラムで管理するためには？

Tags: database, データベース設計

たとえなのですが、ショッピングサイトを作っているとします。
そして化粧品とゲームが買えるとします。
また買った物の履歴を見れる機能もあるとします。

テーブルの設計をするとき、自分だとこのような場合は、
履歴テーブル、化粧品テーブル、ゲームテーブル
と作ります。

化粧品テーブルのカラムは
id, 値段、材料
ゲームテーブルのカラムは
id, 値段、対応ハードウェアとします。

ただここで問題なのは履歴テーブルのカラムです。
単純に考えるとこう考えました。
id, 化粧品id, ゲームid, 時間

しかしこの構造には問題があります。
化粧品idとゲームidのカラムはどちらか一つしか使われないため、後はnullが入ることになります。
さらに、玩具や食品などを追加すると空のカラムが増大していきます。

どのように設計するのが良いでしょうか？ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 複数テーブルとの関連づけについては http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31730/8000 と同様の話題かと思いますが、今回の場合、化粧品とゲームを別テーブルにする必要はあるのでしょうか？例えば、商品テーブル一つにカテゴリ列を設ける、というのでは不都合がありますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。必要があるのかについては、例が悪かったのですがあるとおもっています。例えばゲームには対応ハードウェア、化粧品には材料、というカラムがあった場合一つのテーブルで表現するのは難しいかと思います。リンク先を見させていただきました。アンチパターンの本を読んでいないのと、理解不足があるかもしれませんが、結論としては「どちらか一方にしか関連しない前提があるのですがRDBの制約では表現できません」とあるので、２つのカラムを作ってかつ、制約をかけることもできないという結論なのでしょうか？

Comment: なるほど、そういう背景があったのですね。質問文の下にある「編集」リンクから質問を編集して、そのことが伝わるような例に修正していただくと、他の方にわかりやすいかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。編集しました。

Comment: いただいたリンクの結論を再度考察すると、化粧品テーブルと、ゲームテーブルに履歴テーブルのidをもたせるという結論なのでしょうか？そしてこのidがどちらも同じidを参照しているかについては、RDBでは制御できない、という話でしょうか？

Comment: お寿司さんが想定していたイメージと違う回答のようなので削除します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こういったケースでは、ひとつのテーブルで管理するよりきちんとテーブルを分けて整理するほうが好ましいです。

化粧品テーブルとゲームソフトテーブルで共通の要素（商品名）を抽出した、商品テーブルを作りましょう。
化粧品なら

- 材料

ゲームソフトなら

- 対応ハード
- ジャンル
- 対象年齢

といったことは、**商品に付属する情報とみなせる**ので、付帯情報をまとめるテーブルを作りましょう。

これで、履歴テーブルからnullのカラムを追い出すことができます。

**商品カテゴリテーブル**

```
id, カテゴリ名
1,  化粧品
2,  ゲームソフト
```

**付帯情報種別テーブル**

```
id, 商品カテゴリid, 付帯情報種別名
1,  1,           材料
2,  2,           対応ハードウェア
3,  2,           ジャンル
4,  2,           対象年齢
```

**商品テーブル**

```
id, 商品名
1,  化粧品A
2,  ゲームソフトB
```

**付帯情報テーブル**

```
id, 商品id, 付帯情報種別id, 内容
1,  1,     1,            きれいになるパウダー
2,  2,     2,            イケてるハード
3,  2,     3,            はやりのジャンル
4,  2,     4,            全年齢
```

**履歴テーブル**

```
id, 商品id, 時間
1,  1,     2017-01-01 12:00:00
2,  2,     2017-01-01 13:00:00
3,  2,     2017-01-01 14:00:00
```

例えでは付帯情報テーブルの"内容"に文字列を直接入れていますが、この内容も別テーブルに切り出しても良いでしょう。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。共通の物をまとめたテーブルをつくり、付属する情報は別テーブルに出し、そして別テーブルから共通するテーブルへのIDを持つことで、nullをなくすことができるのですね。ありがとうございます、こちらのやり方でやっていこうと思います。

Answer (score 0):

もし「テーブルを利用するコード側で頑張り尽くす」というのであれば、外部キー制約を使わずテーブル名をレコードに書く、という選択肢を選ぶことができます。

**履歴テーブル**

```
id, 商品id, テーブル名,  対象id, 時間
1,  1,     化粧品,     1       2017-01-01 12:00:00
2,  2,     ゲームソフト,  1       2017-01-01 13:00:00
3,  3,     ゲームソフト,  2       2017-01-01 14:00:00
```